# Experience Reference Letter for ACS Skill Assessment (for 189 type Visa)

Tags: immigration, australia, skilled-migration

I am planning to apply for Australian PR and the 1st step I got to do is "ACS Skill Assessment" by uploading my **PASSPORT**, **DEGREE CERTIFICATE** and **WORK EXPERIENCE LETTER**. My question is regarding Work Experience Letter.

Total Experience                   :   6.8 years

Experience in Current company      : Past 2.8 years

Experience in 1st company          : 4 years

I just have my Experience Letter for my 1st Company which doesn't specify my roles and responsibilities.

Q1 :  Should it be a problem? If so, then what needs to be done? I cant get it anyway.

Q2 :  If I submitted all the docs, and further clarification or any docs needed from me, whether ACS will intimate me to get it?

Expecting a reply.

Comment: Is only reference letter will be sufficient..i dont have salary slip or bank statements to show...will that be enough?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**It is a problem...**

When providing references you need to follow specific standard of letter, below are 2 examples one that got rejected other accepted...

**Successful:**
[image]

**Failed:**
[image]

And when you fail you get following...

[image]

I suggest you make forms for each company that look like former example, then get originals to Australian embassy for notarisation (17GBP per page) and you should be solid...

Comment: Isn't it forbidden to directly copy/paste? In the guide it says: "Generic job
descriptions are not acceptable and will be assessed as not suitable. References with duties copy and
pasted directly from ANZSCO will not be accepted. "